# Retrieve data based on filtered array

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to filter through an array that is based on the post.id comparison, retrieve the value and append it to the likes property.

```
action.data.filter((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length
```

doesn't work as i thought it would, gives me an error that length is not defined

if i do something like

```
 action.data.filter((post) => post.id === 5)
```

it will give me the result im looking for, but this wouldn't work it needs to be dynamic.

```
return {
  ...state, 
  posts: action.data, // maps posts fine,
  likes: action.data.filter((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length // does not do what i want it do :(
 }
```

It should be dynamic, so that any value for that particular post have its own value. What should i do instead  or what could be a solution ?

when its called `{this.props.likes}`

action.id *(gets existing post ids)*

```
console.log(action.id)
```

Outputs this

> [5,2]

Posts data outputs this

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0:
  Likes: (32) 
  createdAt: "2019-04-26T09:38:10.324Z"
  id: 5
  post_content: "ssss"
  title: "React Interview Questionsdd"
  updatedAt: "2019-04-26T09:38:10.324Z"
  userId: 1
  username: "owlmans"
  __proto__: Object
 1: {id: 3, title: "React Interview sssQuestions", post_content: "ggg", 
  username: "owlman", createdAt: "2019-04-24T20:48:36.710Z", …}
  length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

**Actions.js**

```
export const GetPosts = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        return Axios.get('/api/posts/myPosts')
            .then( (res) => {
                 const data = res.data
                 const id = data.map( (post) => post.id)  // gets posts id [5,3]
                 dispatch({type: GET_POSTS, data, id})
             })

    }
}
```

Comment: does your action.id contains array ?

Comment: so the values are within array

Comment: yeah i guess it's an array

Comment: if it's array than you are not comparing correctly

Comment: If it's an array, try checking if the value is in it with `[5, 2].includes(post.id)`

Comment: What should i do instead ?

Comment: m posting answer let me know if it works

Comment: ok let me try that

Comment: so do `action.id.includes(post.id)`

Comment: i get an empty array :(

Comment: `console.log(action.data.filter((post) => post.id === action.id.includes(post.id)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter returns an array of filtered data.. so when you have filtered access the zero index to retrieve Likes length

For the sum of Likes:

```
    action.data.filter((post) => action.id.includes(post.id)).reduce((a,b) => {
     return a.Likes.length + b.Likes.length
    })
```

For the dispersed Likes:

```
    action.data.filter((post) => action.id.includes(post.id)).map((a) => {
     return { postlikes: a.Likes.length }
    })
```

For more details read [filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192463/discussion-on-answer-by-murtaza-hussain-retrieve-data-based-on-filtered-array).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const filtered = action.data.filter((post) => action.id.includes(post.id))

return filtered.map((post,index) => `post ${index} has ${post.Likes.length} likes`)
```

Comment: is their a more dynamic way to do this without using [0] their are multiple arrays and 0 being just one of them, it needs to loop through [1], [2], etc.

Comment: Does that make sense ?

Comment: so you are saying after filtering you are getting multiple entries ? and you want to sum Likes of those entries ? here filtered[0] is post object which is found

Comment: which the values should be dispersed

Comment: for example post 1 contains 32 likes, and post 2 contains 15 likes

Comment: for sure their is 32 likes for post 1, however im expecting 15 to show in another post. Not 32

Comment: i have edited the answer it will give you like this [32,15]

Comment: all of the likes do 3215, which really should be post 1 has 32, and post 2 15 likes. Dispersed .

Comment: does that make sense ?

Comment: you can return anything while mapping its upto you like if you need 
```map((post,index) => `post ${index} has ${post.Likes.length} likes`)``` will give you post 1 has 32 likes and so on each array index

Comment: ^ can you edit the answer cause i think that might work.

Comment: thx, despite this is not working, i think its because props are immutable, and it would only store one value. Could this be the case ?

im calling it like 

`myLikes={this.props.myLikes}`

Answer (score 0):

So you want to know the total likes of the posts? or totallikes of every post?

So if you want to get the sum of likes you can use ```reduce``.

Check the docs here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Also it looks like not every object has a Likes porperty so you have to check it.

```
let totalNumberOfLikes = action.data.posts.reduce( acc, post =>{

 if(post.id == action.id && post.hasOwnProperty('Likes'){
    acc += post.Likes.length
 }
} , 0 );


return {
  ...state, 
  posts: action.data,
  likes: totalNumberOfLikes }
```

If you want to get the likes for every post you are almost there, remember that the `filter` returns an array, so you are checking the property of `Likes` of the array of your filtered posts.

What you want to do is to check the property `Likes` of every post, not the array of filtered posts.

So instead of: 
`action.data.filter((post) => post.id === action.id).Likes.length`. 
you can make something like this :

```
let filteredPosts = action.data.posts.filter( post => post.id == action.id );

let totalLikesForEachPost  =  {}; 

//Here you need an object to keep the record of every like in the post if this has any and an id so you can access the data.
filteredPosts.forEach( post => {
  totalLikesForEachPost[ post.id ] = {  
       totalLikes: post.hasOwnProperty('Likes') ? post.Likes.length : 0,
       id: post.id,
  }
} );


return {
  ...state, 
  posts: action.data,
  likes: totalLikesForEachPost }
```

Comment: totallikes of every post yes, would this be the way to do it ?

Comment: Ive added an edit to my answer that tries to check this

Comment: idk why but its giving me an empty object when i `console.log(totalLikesForEachPost)`

Comment: if you can make a repo in codesandbox or anywhere it would be easier to help!